# file.open() ending up with an infinite loop

Tags: python-3.x, break

I have a small doubt about an online assignment of mine that I completed. So the assignment requires me to open a txt file and make all the characters upper case.

```
fh = open(f)
fhand=fh.read()
for line in fhand:
    line=fhand.rstrip()
    line=fhand.upper()
    print(line)
    break
```

this is the code that I used. If I don't add the break statement, I'm ending up with an infinite loop. Can anyone explain why this is so?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you read the entire file into the `fhand` and then your `for` loop iterates over every character in `fhand` as it is a big string at this point.

So for each character in your input, you then ultimately print the entire input (capitalized).

You likely want to do something more like:

```
with open("file.txt") as file_in:
    for line in file_in.readlines():
        print(line.strip().upper())
```

Thanks to @bloueteeth for pointing out that `readlines()` is not actually needed here and this can be simplified to:

```
with open("file.txt") as file_in:
    for line in file_in:
        print(line.strip().upper())
```